# How to convert ResolveInstructionData object in to JAXBElement object in Java?

Tags: 2011, core-service, java, sdl-tridion, xml

I am trying to set the JAXBElement  in to the PublishInstructionData using the below function but getting the error on runtime as 
**Exception in thread "main" com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreServicePublishCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: publishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.**

```
PublishInstructionData publishInstructionData = new PublishInstructionData();
ResolveInstructionData resolveInstructionData = new ResolveInstructionData();
resolveInstructionData.setIncludeChildPublications(false);
JAXBElement jaxbElement =    new JAXBElement(new QName(ResolveInstructionData.class.getSimpleName()), ResolveInstructionData.class, resolveInstructionData);
publishInstructionData.setResolveInstruction(jaxbElement);
```

Comment: Is this not the same root issue as in your previous question?

Comment: Here, I want to know if I am doing the correct conversion into JAXBElement as I am getting the null value.